# Parallelism in RxJava

Tags: android, concurrency, parallel-processing, kotlin, rx-java2

I have some doubts about how to properly use parallel threads in RxJava with an Android app (Kotlin). I have this app that reads some RSS feeds. The user request to update all the feeds using this method:

```
override fun updateAllFeeds(): Completable {
    return menu()
            .map {
                val feeds = mutableListOf<String>()
                it.forEach { menuSection ->
                    menuSection.options.forEach { menuOption ->
                        menuOption.feed?.forEach { feed ->
                            if (!feeds.contains(feed)) feeds.add(feed)
                        }
                    }
                }
                feeds
            }
            .flatMapObservable {
                // Get each item from List
                Observable.fromIterable(it)
            }
            .flatMapCompletable { feedUrl ->
                // Update each feed
                rssDataStore.updateFeed(feedUrl)
            }
}
```

That `Completable` is used later here:

```
val task = rssRepository.updateAllFeeds().subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
                .observeOn(postExecutionThread.scheduler)
```

Where threadExecutor is a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with maximumPoolSize = 5.

I had the idea that the rssDataStore.updateFeed(feedUrl) part will be executed in parallel because of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` used in subscribeOn, but in Logcat I can see it is only running one at a time, sequentially, and the Observer's `onComplete` is fired when the last feed is updated. Is there a way to specify that rssDataStore.updateFeed(feedUrl) should be executed in parallel but get the `onComplete` only when the last thread has finished?

Comment: [Suggested reading](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#parallel-processing). Parallelism requires flows individually to be run on a Scheduler; `updateFeed(feedUrl).subscribeOn(yourScheduler)`.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd, that was what I needed.